# Contacts unexpectidly added to Mailing Groups (by Admin)

Tags: groups

I'm using CiviCRM with Wordpress and have around 1500 contacts.

I have 3 groups with around 120 contacts in each group which I use for mailings.

I sent a bulk email to one of the groups then around 10 minutes later all 3 groups had 550 contacts in them.

When I look in the Groups tab of one of the newly added contacts I can see that they were added to all 3 groups at the same time and says "Added (by Admin)".

Has anyone come across this before or have any idea why it might have happened?

Is there a way to find contacts based on date added to a group so I can search for them and remove them from the groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From UI i don't think there is any way you can get history of contact being added to group. If you have hands of experience in writing sql statements than you can use `civicrm_subscription_history` table in Civicrm to track down about all history of contact added to group by dates.

Comment: Thank you. I found them using: SELECT *  FROM `civicrm_subscription_history` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2020-01-02 14:30:00' AND '2020-01-02 15:00:00' but now I think I need to delete them from that table and from the civicrm_group_contact table?

Comment: can you mark this as answered if you feel the post was helpful